# jdbc URL to connect to Impala using keytab file

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, cloudera, impala

I am trying to connect to `Impala` using `keytab` file but I didn't find exact URL to connect with keytab. I have gone through [Cloudera documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-12-x/topics/impala_jdbc.html#impala_jdbc), but it does not mention using keytab file with principal to connect to Impala. What will be the JDBC URL to connect to Impala using keytab file?

Answer (score 3):

As described in the [User Guide](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/other/connectors/impala-jdbc/latest/Cloudera-JDBC-Driver-for-Impala-Install-Guide.pdf), section "Using Kerberos", Impala JDBC driver supports three methods of getting Kerberos Subject:

> 1. ...The driver tries to obtain the Subject from the current thread's inherited AccessControlContext. If the AccessControlContext contains
>      multiple Subjects, the driver uses the most recent Subject.
> 2. The driver checks the `java.security.auth.login.config` system property for a JAAS configuration. If a JAAS configuration is
>      specified, the driver uses that information to create a LoginContext
>      and then uses the Subject associated with it.
> 3. The driver checks the KRB5_CONFIG and KRB5CCNAME system environment variables for a Kerberos ticket cache. The driver uses the information
>      from the cache to create a LoginContext and then uses the Subject
>      associated with it.

You can control which method driver will be using via `KrbAuthType` parameter in connection URL, otherwise it will try each method one by one.

So, all you should do to use keytab file (method# 2) is

1. create a `jaas.conf` file specifying keytab location, principal, etc.
2. set system property `java.security.auth.login.config` in your program (or use
   JVM startup argument `-Djava.security.auth.login.config=</some-path-to/jaas.conf>`) pointing to the location of that `jaas.conf`, and
3. in your JDBC connection URL, set **`...AuthMech=1;`**`KrbRealm=<YOUR-REALM.COM>;KrbHostFQDN=your.impalad.host.com;KrbServiceName=<impala-service-principal>` for Kerberos authentication

...before trying to connect.

Alternatively, `kinit` using your keytab so that ticket cache contains necessary TGT before calling your Java application (essentially, use method 3 above).

Comment: I am able to connect to Impala now using standalone class. But we do have dynamic datasource creation using hibernate configuration file. Is there any way to specify system properties in hibernate config file?

Comment: Not a hybernate expert, so can't answer that. But I believe option 3 could be a better choice for you -- just define `KRB5_CONFIG` and `KRB5CCNAME` env. vars, `kinit -k -t <your.keytab> <principal@REALM>` and you don't need to setup any system properties.